# Set Legend Spacing in ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2, legend

I am trying to create a plot in R using ggplot2. The figure looks great when displayed in R, but when I write it to pdf the labels in the legend slightly overlap the different color lines they are defining. How do I add white space between entries so that this does not happen?

Answer (score 0):

Without code example it is hard to say, but if you don't see this problem in the R display and you see it in the pdf, you can try to increase the pdf output size. When rendering a pdf, the font size is kept and the elements of the graph are more squeezed if the output size is smaller than the displayed one.

```
p<-ggplot(mpg,aes(cyl,year))+geom_point()
ggsave('yourfile.pdf',p,width=10,height=10) # default is 7 on my install
```

I don't know if it is possible to change the spacing, but I don't see any parameters for that in the [`theme()`](http://docs.ggplot2.org/current/theme.html) or [`element_text()`](http://docs.ggplot2.org/current/element_text.html) documentation